# How I can remove the spread operator as whole dynamically from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Actually, I want to remove the spread operator or the last entry filter from the params object dynamically.

```
const params = {
                    name: query.name,
                    age: query.age,
                    gender: query.gender
                    ...filter,
}

const condition = true;
      
if (condition) {
  //remove    ...filter
  delete  params.filter //does not work
}
```

Expedted output after the condition applied,

```
console.log(params)

 {
      name: query.name,
      age: query.age,
      gender: query.gender    
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking.  Spread doesn't get added to an object, it causes things *to be added to* an object.  You wouldn't delete `filter` you would `delete` the things that `...filter` added.

Comment: Filter is not object property. `...filter` destructs `filter` object and merges with `params` object. You cant delete it

Comment: Why not just spread the `filter` object in `params` object only if condition is not true?

Comment: oh okay, I understood. I need to delete all the entries   one by one added due to spread operator if condition is true. 

Yousaf's ans is also good. :-) 

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the condition into the spread:

```
const params = {
        name: query.name,
        age: query.age,
        gender: query.gender,
        ...(condition && filter),
}
```

Comment: @SatishHawalppagol But that's not what the OP wants. OP wants to get rid of any and all properties added from the `filter` object, which could potentially be several or it could be none at all. Also, objects are unordered so there is no *last* property.

Comment: Thank you Lennholm, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` to enumerate the keys of filter object and delete from the params object.

```js
const query = {
  name: 'foo',
  age: 42,
  gender: 'unknown'
}
const filter = {
  bar: 'baz'
}

const params = {
  name: query.name,
  age: query.age,
  gender: query.gender,
  ...filter,
}

const condition = true;

if (condition) {
  //remove    ...filter
  Object.keys(filter).forEach(k => {
      delete params[k]
  })
}

console.log(params)
```

Comment: but when filter contains `name` property ;P

Comment: @Estradiaz you have to make an assumption :)

Comment: "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'",
It gives error

Comment: @SatishHawalppagol it was just a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the last item in a javascript object

```
 var lastElement =  params[Object.keys(params)[Object.keys(params).length - 1]] 
 // "filter"
```

Now delete the last element from object

```
console.log(delete lastElement);   // returns true
```

Comment: That won't work: JS objects don't have property order and `filter` may have multiple properties